# TypeError: Can only concatenate str when I'm using eval()

Tags: python, eval

so I'm encountering this error:

```
print(eval(sol))
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

With this code:

```py
userInput1 = str(input("Enter equation. (use ** for exponents): "))
userInput2 = input("Enter value of A: ")
x = userInput2
sol = eval(str("userInput1"))
print(eval(sol))
```

but if I change the code this:

```py
userInput1 = str(input("Enter equation. (use ** for exponents): "))
x = 2
sol = eval(str("userInput1"))
print(eval(sol))
```

it will print the intended answer, for example, if `userInput1` is `x+2`

Why am I encountering the `TypeError` in the first version of the code? Thanks a lot in advance

Hello, so I'm encountering this error:

```
print(eval(sol))
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: There's no need to call `str()` around `input()`. It always returns a string.

Comment: There's no point in calling `eval()` here: `sol = eval(str("userInput1"))`. It's the same as `sol = userInput1`.

Comment: Noted on these, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`userInput2` is not casted to int in your code, so python interpreter thinks it's string (output from `input` function), you should cast it by:

```py
userInput2 = int(input("Enter value of A: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by Jaroszewski Piotr, the problem is that `input` returns strings, so you need to cast it to `int`. But I think also that your code contains unnecessary steps. For information here is a proposal.

```py
equation = input("Enter equation. (use ** for exponents): ")
x = int(input("Enter value of A: "))
print(f"{equation} = {eval(equation)}")

# Enter equation. (use ** for exponents): x + 2
# Enter value of A: 3
# x + 2 = 5
```